# React setState array is appending the same item twice on second call onward

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm building a simple twitter clone with React and I'm facing a weird behaviour when creating a new Tweet. Right now, how it works is that I locally store a tweets array using useState and I use setState to add the new tweet into the array. According to my initial approach it works fine on the first time creating a tweet. However, on subsequent creation of tweet it is being appended twice into the array. So, all the tweets that was created after the first one will have their own respective duplicate.

Here is the screen shot of the problem[image]

Here are the respective code:

Home.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { MainContentWrapper, StyledHeader } from "../style";
import { Tweet } from "../Tweet";
import { CreateTweet } from "./CreateTweet";

function Home() {
  const [ tweets, setTweets ] = useState([{
    id: 1,
    content: 'Alyssa\'s First Tweet!',
    createdAt: '2021-10-28T21:33:41.453Z',
    user: {
      username: 'aly',
      name: 'Alyssa Holmes',
    }
  }, {
    id: 2, 
    content: 'Hello Twitter Clone!',
    createdAt: '2021-10-28T21:33:41.453Z',
    user: {
      username: 'martinxz',
      name: 'Martin San Diego'
    }
  }, {
    id: 3,
    content: 'Going to starbucks today :D',
    user: {
      username: 'rickyyy',
      name: 'Rick & Morty'
    }
  }]);
  
  const createTweetHandler = (newTweet) => {
    console.log('Appending new tweet into state', newTweet); 
    setTweets((prevTweets) => {
      console.log('setState');
      prevTweets.push(newTweet);
      return [...prevTweets];
    })
  }

  return (
    <MainContentWrapper>
      <StyledHeader>
        <h3>Home</h3>
      </StyledHeader>
    <CreateTweet onCreateTweet={createTweetHandler}/>
      { tweets.map((tweet) => {
        return <Tweet key={tweet.id} tweet={tweet} />
      }) }
    </MainContentWrapper>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

CreateTweet.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { authUser } from '../../authentication/authenticationSlice';
import styled from 'styled-components/macro';
import avatarImg from "../../../assets/images/avatar_placeholder.jpg";
import { Button } from '../../../shared/Button.styled';
import { MainContentWrapper, StyledAvatar,StyledText } from '../style';

const CreateTweetWrapper = styled(MainContentWrapper)`
  & form {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
    grid-gap: 5px 20px;
    align-items: center;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  }

`

const StyledInput = styled.textarea`
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.background};
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.text};
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  resize: none;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
`;

const ButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  grid-column: 2;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
`;

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  justify-self: end;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 15px;
`

export function CreateTweet({onCreateTweet}) {
  const user = useSelector(authUser);
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      content: "",
    },
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const newTweet = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      content: data.content,
      user: {
        username: user.username,
        name: user.attributes.name
      }
    }
    console.log('happens here');
    onCreateTweet(newTweet);
  }
 
  return (
    <CreateTweetWrapper>
      <form>
        <StyledAvatar src={`${avatarImg}`}/>
        <StyledInput rows="1" placeholder="What's happening?" {...register("content")} />
        <ButtonWrapper>
          <StyledText> Icons </StyledText>
          <StyledButton buttonType="secondary" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>Tweet</StyledButton>
        </ButtonWrapper>
      </form>
    </CreateTweetWrapper>
  )
}
```

**UPDATE**: I managed to solve the bug (but not sure why my initial code won't work) by using the spread operator instead in the createTweetHandler function. So I am assuming it is something to do with immutability of states. Could someone explain to me why my previous code doesn't work?

Here's the updated code the apparently solved the duplicate problem:

```
  const createTweetHandler = (newTweet) => {
    console.log('Appending new tweet into state', newTweet); 
    setTweets((prevTweets) => {
      return [...prevTweets, newTweet];
    })
  }
```

And here's the old code that was causing the issue:

```
  const createTweetHandler = (newTweet) => {
    console.log('Appending new tweet into state', newTweet); 
    setTweets((prevTweets) => {
      console.log('setState');
      prevTweets.push(newTweet);
      return [...prevTweets];
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

You are mutating the previous state when you push into it.

```
setTweets((prevTweets) => {
  console.log('setState');
  prevTweets.push(newTweet); // <-- mutates state!!
  return [...prevTweets];
})
```

The reason is typically that your app is rendered into a `React.StrictMode` component which invokes *certain* functions/lifecycle methods twice as a way to help you detect unintentional side-effects, like state mutations.

[Detecting unexpected side effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally ***double-invoking*** the following
> functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - Functions passed to ***`useState`***, `useMemo`, or `useReducer` <-- this

This means on the second invocation you are seeing the result of the mutation, i.e. the first `.push`, and then a second `.push` occurs and thus the net result is that ***two*** new elements were added!

## Solution

As you've discovered, the fix is to *not* mutate the state, but to instead apply the immutable update pattern. Redux has a great explanation found [here](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns).

The idea is to create a shallow copy of the state and not effect any changes to the existing state.

```
setTweets((prevTweets) => {
  return [
    ...prevTweets, // shallow copy into new array reference
    newTweet,      // append new element
  ];
})
```

or

```
setTweets((prevTweets) => {
  return prevTweets.concat(newTweet); // append and return new array reference
})
```

Comment: Still appending twice for me

Comment: @GameFromScratch Do you think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduced the issue we could take a look at? Or would this be better as a new SO post? If you create a new post feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can take a look when available.

Comment: Ok, I could do create try creating a running codesandbox. One thing different about my problem is that the setState happens inside a useEffect function.

Comment: @GameFromScratch Ok, see if you can create a sandbox that we can take a look at, it might just be something trivial.